# A movie about a female cop going after two bored young lads that killed a woman

Tags: identify-this-movie, crime

I watched an excellent movie before and now want to re-watch it, but can't remember its name.

Here's the plot:

**Setting**: California, or somewhere in the wild West, a ranch or something like that, wild and unpopulated.

Two young lads, bored, trying to find something exciting to do. So they go to a parking lot, spotting a random lady, and abduct her and get her killed.

One of the two lads reads a lot about forensics, so he knows how to evade the cops. And I remember a scene of him throwing his forensics textbook into the fireplace.

But there's a super smart and beautiful female cop, who managed thru this hard case.

At last, the 2 lads were found out by the beautiful cop. And there's a scene where the beautiful female cop is about to fall to the ground from the 2nd floor of a house but one lad saved her.

Can any bud tell me the title of this movie?

Answer (score 10):

[Murder By Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_by_Numbers)

> Richard Haywood, a wealthy and popular high-schooler, secretly teams up with another rich kid in his class, brilliant nerd Justin "Bonaparte" Pendleton. His erudition, especially in forensic matters, allows them to plan elaborately perfect murders as a perverse form of entertainment.

At the end of the film:

> Cassie pursues Richard, who tricks her into going out onto an unstable balcony. Richard strangles Cassie, but she fights back and pushes him over the railing, and he falls to his death. But, before Cassie can get back inside, the porch breaks. Justin saves her, and she tells him that he will likely get a light sentence.

Comment: Seems like a good match. It also takes place in California, IIRC.

Comment: Yup, looks like this is the one. The wild west part doesn't apply though. In any case there was no forensics in the times of the wild west.